# android retrofit is giving null values of response maybe there ism problem with end points

Tags: android, retrofit

i'm new to android and using retrofit for the first time.
i've implemented all the things but retrofit is giving null values of responses.
this is my sample request:
http://192.168.1.0/demo/kdemo//webservice/api.php?query=user.auttentication&user_name=admin&password=admin

for this I'm taking base url as :
     BASE_URL="http://192.168.1.0/demo/kdemo//webservice/"
    and End point in interface as :

```
@GET("api.php")
Call<UserAuthenticaiton> getUserAuthentication(@Query("user.auttentication") 
String userAuttentication,
                                               @Query("user_name") String 
user_name,
                                               @Query("password") String 
password);
```

JSon viewer is giving values but retrofit is not..
This is Api call:

```
ApiInterface apiService= ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
           Call<UserAuthenticaiton> call=apiService.getUserAuthentication("user.auttentication","admin","admin");
           call.enqueue(new Callback<UserAuthenticaiton>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(Call<UserAuthenticaiton> call, Response<UserAuthenticaiton> response) {
                   String id=response.body().getId();
                   String error=response.body().getError();
                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Id: "+id+" Error: "+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Intent intentNew=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                   startActivity(intentNew);
               }

               @Override
               public void onFailure(Call<UserAuthenticaiton> call, Throwable t) {
                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           });
```

Comment: Shouldn't be your first `@Query` be "query" instead of "user.auttentication"?

Comment: is this spelling Correct: `user.auttentication` ?

Comment: this is the spelling that was given by client in parameters file

Comment: These are parameters:
Parameters:
Query: user.auttentication
Send : user_name     e.g admin
password                   e.g admin 
Return :
id           e.g  ba98b3e3c32196208dbeee99c8036ecb
Return Type : json

Comment: Can you post the enqueue method please and you Retrofit client too.?

Comment: public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL="http://182.50.148.24/demo/kdemo//webservice/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit=null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(){
    if(retrofit==null){
        retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
        return retrofit;
    }

    }

Comment: Please check your server endpoint as well. `192.168.1.0` is a private network accessible from your PC or laptop. So please check if it is also accessible from your mobile, or you may need to come to the same WiFi. Just check

Comment: Please edit in the question

Comment: i've added enque method with my question